# Finding the height of a custom dialogBox

Tags: android, dialog

I have a custom dialog box (`cameraTipDialog ctd`) that I need to position at a certain (x,y) position. That position is based on the location of button on the screen. I need to put the dialog box at position:

```
(int) ((ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.infoButton)).getY() - HEIGHT OF MY DIALOG BOX;'
```

But I Cannot figure out how to get the height of my custom dialog box. It's height is 'wrap content' so when I do getLayoutParams.getHeight() I get -1.

Following other ideas on StackOverflow I tried using `(ctd.findViewById(R.id.dialog_root_layout)).getHeight()` but that crashes the app saying that it couldn't find item with id dialog_root_layout.

Show Layout Code:

```
    cameraTipDialog ctd = new cameraTipDialog(submitHome.this);
    Window window = ctd.getWindow();
    (ctd.findViewById(R.id.dialog_root_layout)).getHeight()
    WindowManager.LayoutParams wlp = window.getAttributes();
    wlp.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
    wlp.x = (int) ((ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.infoButton)).getX();
    wlp.y = (int) ((ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.infoButton)).getY() - DIALOG HEIGHT;
    window.setAttributes(wlp);
    ctd.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    ctd.show();
```

Dialog box XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/dialog_root_layout"
android:layout_width="300dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
android:layout_marginLeft="16sp"
android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
android:background="@drawable/popup_background">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
    android:text="@string/tipsForSuccess"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/header" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="text here."
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: What type of class is CameraTipDialog?

Comment: The class extends Dialog

Answer (score 0):

To get the actual height you can use `getRootView().getMeasuredHeight()` on your `dialog_root_layout`. But you can only do that once the view has been measured so you need to do your calculations in an `OnShowListener`. Modified code looks like this:

```
cameraTipDialog ctd = new cameraTipDialog(this);

ctd.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
    @Override
    public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
        Dialog ctd = (Dialog) dialog;

        View dialogRootLayout = ctd.findViewById(R.id.dialog_root_layout);
        int dialogHeight = dialogRootLayout.getRootView().getMeasuredHeight();

        Window window = ctd.getWindow();
        WindowManager.LayoutParams wlp = window.getAttributes();
        wlp.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
        wlp.x = (int) ((ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.infoButton)).getX();
        wlp.y = (int) ((ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.infoButton)).getY() - dialogHeight;
        window.setAttributes(wlp);
        window.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    }
});

ctd.show();
```